# Joomla - Save article from frontend does not work with Allrounder-Template

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, frontend, joomla3.0, joomla-template

I use Joomla Version 3.8.6 with "The ALLROUNDER 3 - Joomla Template" in Version 1.1 and I have a problem when I edit an article via frontend. When I want to save the article nothing happens. All other buttons (close, etc...) work correctly.

In my browser console I get this error message when I click on the save button:

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isValid' of null
>     at Object.Joomla.submitbutton (index.php?view=form&layout=edit&a_id=1&catid=8&return=aHR0cDovL3Rlc3QudHNjLXpldXpsZWJlbi5kZS9pbmRleC5waHA=:67)
>     at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

This error happens for all different types of users (Editor as well as Super-Administrator)

I deleted the template completely from my webspace and did a new clean install but the error is still there. I tried to disable Jquery-Scripts in the header as well as all other Javascripts but this did not help. I also disabled sequentially all plugins, but the error was still active. Further, I set up textfilter for all users to "No Filter", but the error was still active.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried the default Joomla template(s), do they work? Otherwise, I really would not rely on a 5 year old template to function properly in the latest Joomla release (and hopefully a newer php version). The template info says it's for Joomla 3.*, but perhaps that only means 3.0.*.

Comment: Yes I tried it with the default Joomla template, it worked. But I also tried it with this version of the Allrounder-Template: http://bakual.net/download/%7Bless%7D-allrounder/less-allrounder-2-5-1.html It is explicitly for Joomla 3.8 and was released 31. January 2018. With this template I have exact the same error like I have with the "original" Allrounder template.